# Gather mac addresses of domain computers, preferably from command line

Tags: windows-server-2000, mac-address

In preparing to move to a domain and SCCM to manage machines in a new office I need to gather their MAC addresses.  I could go from machine to machine, run ipconfig and gather the ip, but that would be time consuming.  I can also look at a list of machines through the Network window, then work down the list pinging them, then looking up the ip in arp, still time consuming, but I wouldn't have to leave my office.  Is there a better way?  Possibly a series of command line tools?  The current domain is managed by Win server 2000 so I have limited domain tools, and I am working with a win8 desktop.

Comment: There are a number of free tools that can do a ping sweep of your network, which will give you a list of computer names, ip addresses and the corresponding MAC addresses.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can use a couple nifty tricks already available. This only works if the machines will respond to a broadcasted ping:

`ping 192.168.x.255` (where the ip is appropriate to your network) Then: `arp -a` to list the routing table. It'll contain any IP address that responded. Again, it's not fool-proof but it does return a majority of Windows machines in particular.

Comment: Yup, that or check the DHCP leases and reservations.

Comment: I am getting an error with that ping command, it doesn't seem to recognize the ip

Comment: I think he's saying you need to ping the broadcast address of your LAN. Eg if your range is 192.168.1.0/24 then your broadcast address is 192.168.1.255.

Comment: @john exactly. This will populate the ARP table appropriately.